# How to get listed in the iOS 8 share menu to receive an URL from Safari?

Tags: iphone, air, ios8

I'm working on an iOS 8 iPhone app with Adobe Air. I would like to enable users to send an URL to my app from the Safari browser. How to get listed in the **share menu** of iOS 8?
This is the share process:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using UIActivityViewController.. More information and example code can be found here http://shrikar.com/blog/2014/12/11/ios-sharing-with-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swift/

Comment: But how to do it without that card feature? I would like to invoke my "full" app.

Comment: Yes you need to implement this UIActivityItemSource delegate protocol and return the url which you want to show up in the share menu

Comment: Sorry if my questions wan't clear enough. I don't want to share the URL from my app to another but *receive* the URL from others apps, e.g. Safari browser. I guess I need to add something to the  Info.plist file of my app?